# how to order by foreign key hql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, hql

i need to do a query that is order by foreign key
the tables:

[image]

this is my code:

```
@Transactional
    public List<Producto> busquedaPaginada(int currPosition, int pageSize, String sSearch, int iSortCol_0, String sSortDir_0){

        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

            String columna = buscarColumna(iSortCol_0);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Producto> lista = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("From Producto P Where P.descripcion like '"+sSearch+"%' order by P."+columna+" "+sSortDir_0)
                .setMaxResults(pageSize).setFirstResult(currPosition).list();

            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
            return lista;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }finally{
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close();
        }

    }

    private String buscarColumna(int iSortCol_0){
        String columna="";
        try {

            if(iSortCol_0==0)
                columna="idproducto";
            else if (iSortCol_0==1) 
                columna="anio";
            else if (iSortCol_0==2)
                columna="clave";
            else if (iSortCol_0==3)
                columna="pventa";
            else if (iSortCol_0==4)
                columna="iddepto.depto";
            else
                return "idproducto";



        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return columna;
    }
```

i try with this query's:

1. Producto P Where P.descripcion like '%' order by P.iddepto.depto asc
2. Producto P Where P.descripcion like '%' order by P.iddepto asc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` the tables and then you can `ORDER BY` any column. Alias the tables as `p` and `d`.

```
SELECT d.iddepto, d.ideptto, p.iproducto, p.name, p.descripcion
FROM depto d
JOIN producto p ON d.iddepto = p.iddepto
WHERE p.descripcion like '%'
ORDER BY p.iddepto ASC
```

**WARNING**: Please note that you have a SQL injection vulnerability in your code. You should sanitize your input for `sSearch`, `columna`, and `sSortDir_0`.